# Eloquent Relations: how to order topics by newest posts?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I created a table like this (table name: supports):

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('supports')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->text('body');
$table->timestamps();
```

in support model I do this:

```
public function supports()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Support::class , 'parent_id' , 'id');
}

public function latestSupport()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Support::class,'parent_id','id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->latest();
}
```

And Finally I try call this function (in model) in controller:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $input)
{
    $query->where('parent_id',null);
    $query->with('latestSupport');

    return $query->latest();
 }
```

It return list of root (topics) ...But It couldn't sort roots by newest post for each root.

Could you please tell me the wrong?

---

**Edit:**
in controller:

```
$supports = Support::Search($input)->paginate(20);
```

Comment: What is `Support`? Is it the topics?

Comment: By the way, I think you are misusing the scope functions. They are not supposed to return a result but a query builder. `paginate($pagination)` should be called in the controller.

Comment: @Namoshek thanks. I do it. but I get same result,

Comment: It shouldn't change the result - it is only a code smell in my opinion (especially from a reusability perspective). But what about my question in the first comment?

Comment: @Namoshek    yes, each root record (as topic or as question)  has some children  (as post or as answer).

Comment: Do you even have a `created_at` column on your `supports` table? You didn't show it in the first code snippet.

Comment: @Namoshek Yes I do.

Comment: Take this query and put it in your controller and this will work : select * from (select parent_id, id from supports order by created_at desc) as tmp order by created_at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the following, where we sort on the related `created_at` instead of the root one. To achieve this, we need to perform a subquery (or perform a join).

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $input)
{
    $query->with('latestSupport');
    $query->whereNull('parent_id');

    $query->select('supports.*', \DB::raw(
        '(SELECT MAX(s2.created_at) FROM supports as s2 WHERE supports.id = s2.parent_id) as sort'
    ));
    $query->orderBy('sort');

    return $query;
}
```

I also replaced `where('parent_id', null)` by `whereNull('parent_id')` to utilize the native SQL grammar for this.

Comment: Thanks. it works. But If a root has not a child, It can not be sortable by its own created_at.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$supports = Support::Search($input)->paginate(20);
```

with

```
$supports = Support::Search($input)->latest()->paginate(20);
```